# Twisted web server processing request multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, twisted, twisted.web

I have copied the example of twisted web server from the official site.here is the code :

```
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import reactor, endpoints

class Counter(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    numberRequests = 0

    def render_GET(self, request):
        self.numberRequests += 1
        request.setHeader(b"content-type", b"text/plain")
        content = u"I am request #{}\n".format(self.numberRequests)
        return content.encode("ascii")

endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, "tcp:8080").listen(server.Site(Counter()))
reactor.run()
```

When I send a request on `8080` I get output as :

```
I am request #1
I am request #3
I am request #5
```

It should be :

```
I am request #1
I am request #2
I am request #3
```

Why is this?

Comment: Check your browser’s developer tools for requests for favicon.ico.

Comment: @Ry- thanks that was the issue.